# Typescript: type inference of followed arguments

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, type-inference

I have some types structures of games events and I divided them to chess events and quiz events. Now I'd like Typescript and Intellisense of VSCode to inference exact type, by narrowing it by Function arguments like so:

```
(() => {
    // Narrowing by Function arguments

    send(EventType.CHESS, "goback", {gameId: "1", count: 5}); //allowed
    send(EventType.QUIZ, "answer", {gameId: "2", body: "my answer is..."}, {timeout: 1000}); //allowed
    send(EventType.QUIZ, "make_move", {gameId: "3", from: "2D", to: "4E"}, {timeout: 1000}); //not allowed, should lead to error because "make_move" is CHESS event.

    //send(EventType.QUIZ, /*here intelisense should suggest only QUIZ event names, instead of all of them*/
})();
```

Here goes rest of the code, all types & `send` function:

```
type EventAny<TYPE extends EventType, EventList extends Record<string, any>> = { [K in keyof EventList]:
    { evt: TYPE, evn: K, evd: EventList[K] }
}[keyof EventList];

type EventChess = EventAny<EventType.CHESS, ChessEventList>;
type EventQuiz = EventAny<EventType.QUIZ, QuizEventList>;

type NetEvent = (EventChess | EventQuiz);

enum EventType {
    CHESS   = 0,
    QUIZ    = 1,
}

interface EventData { // will hold some common params
    gameId: string;
}

//

interface ChessEventList {
    "make_move": EventData & {
        from: string;
        to: string;
    }

    "goback": EventData & {
        count: number;
    }
}

interface QuizEventList {
    "answer": EventData & {
        body: string;
    }

    "rate_current": EventData & {
        rate: number;
    }
}

//

interface SomeSendOptions {
    timeout?: number;
}

function send(evt: NetEvent["evt"], evn: NetEvent["evn"], evd: NetEvent["evd"], options?: SomeSendOptions) {
    //[...]
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAgokAeAKgTQAoxQQAewSAJgM6wLJbgQA0NSwAMgJaXBGkXUAlCAGMA9gCdyGbuI6IA5swCG6AHyqoAXigBvKAG0A0lDlQA1hBCiAZi2SduAXQBcAKCgfdROMGdRcBMwQcIh+hkFw5H7wrA7ARo5QAL6uSfoWVrYx9lzAjgDcrq6gkHbAAMIAFhCU1NrZqOgYDfSQAHTlABIwAMo9zFU1lA1xqoUl0A0AigCuHABeWmVomC0MbVMAqgCSAFrMswsjuWNFE1AAchDADUsAFA2DtVAAPmWH8wCUha5IMwC2ZVa0B07k8XV6PU82gADIwwR4tntPEsAIzwlKuORkcTWJTCSa0YAAESUwCUXgA9JSoAB3DgAGwZUEqogZ5CglFE-2gYn+-1EiCgYCU4iU-0oCKg8nFEG2UU5wFkCkKmOpRWxEFx+OgT2GRLiuilACJ-koLAB9AUIY3RImk8lQABkRpRKOs4m5fhkcnkhTdnmAom9St9-s8mJRxvkogARvizLayg6KS7QQGPGIZsg-IgAbGteGPClMZrtQSoB9jtxXZ5jSpKLStUmGinnbWA7HROQQCHlX6pZG62KyBbhDNxOJWC37WTUx23SOILn84XB6kiuqscgtXiKz1uRAehQAPJgYAcQXUdOBjg80QzYAAfhX-wL4lVRWs2eEF8FnIoO5gl8S5rgafRjWA41HAiUJQJuIkIOCRBoIiBUrgQ1gkMiVCoFEc9L0QSgXygA8eWPRByDPP8iM+BdqX0NomMcDdXC3O47jozQNBvDxqUuUVPXpBQoFjEAoAAMR-GioFFeQAVYSUpUoQC1naCE+mYaM4wTY1mB0GUeXlPxjVRPSoCzHMoAAViSb4oGpJQmVEJtyGU1SiWBDYdn2KB6yIptxHMgzZWMvyACZzK7HsTP+cSG0CkxKCYtpjSSfSL3vR8-FRGE8rs-IHMpJyGRciA3JRFTKIeTz1iRXzTXNCArVEG19MMuUFWNABmcyPS9CLiXMoMTIAFhgNKMrvCAHxA3L8vs6lEFEHgSrK8hmEoVkZnZKAGQgJQOSDIhJwkUSRCUGYVL8s1LWtCBjSSqANKhYJWDaIoUWpKryBq1gvPq5hKQAKmqKcTB3BkuCQa6tofXbKBmeR5BqHhBQZcT6u8VgoEQWVKGYORuAOjkbFkpk8NsYBqn+YHKVST5OJ+IA)

Comment: You should probably make sure to ask just one question per SO post; one seems to be how to define `NetEvent` properly, and the other seems to be how to spread those properties into  function arguments.  Which one is the primary question?  In either case, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAJB4W) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining (once you limit to just a single primary question here); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes it works, can I ask, is it possible to use Your `SendArgs` type along with additional last argument? For example: `function send(...[evt, evn, evd]: SendArgs, options?: Options) {[...]}` - it yells about rest parameter has to be last. Reversing the order could potentialy fix it, but option param is optional.

Comment: @jcalz it works in halfway I guess, coz it doesnt narrow type along when you types on keyboard: `send(EventType.QUIZ, [blinking cursor]`. At that point Intelisense should suggest narrowed set of parameters, but it suggest all of them, even unmatched.

Comment: How it works? `type SendArgs = NetEvent extends infer N ? N extends NetEvent ?` what is gonna be under `N` ? SendArgs doesnt require any arguments...

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post so that it asks only one of the two questions I mentioned in my first comment, and then we can focus on answering it?  I don't feel comfortable engaging further unless that happens.

Comment: @jcalz I've joined all of informations and questions into one consistent question. Hope it will deserve some help.

Comment: You're still asking two questions: "I want to do this and this" is still two things, especially if the single solution (a discriminated union type) doesn't work as you desire for one of them.  Maybe I'll look at it further but I do wish you had actually complied with my request after this amount of back-and-forth. 

Comment: @jcalz ok, I've focused whole SO question on most important question from previous ones

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbvZBm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that it sufficient. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write `send()` so that it accepts the right arguments and rejects the wrong ones, but if you want IntelliSense hinting where you are only given suggestions for the next argument that are valid given the previous arguments, then you probably want `send()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of the `evt` parameter, and the type `N` of the subsequent `evn` parameter.  Perhaps like this:

```
interface SendArgMap {
    [EventType.CHESS]: ChessEventList;
    [EventType.QUIZ]: QuizEventList;
}

function send<
    T extends keyof SendArgMap,
    N extends keyof SendArgMap[T]
>(evt: T, evn: N, evd: SendArgMap[T][N], options?: SomeSendOptions) {
    //[...]
}
```

Here we've defined a `SendArgMap` helper interface which encodes the relationship between `evt`, `evn`, and `evd` as a sequence of [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  The compiler understands and infers such generic indexed accesses fairly well, which is why it's a good solution to give you the kind of IntelliSense hinting you're looking for.

Note that `SendArgMap` is just a helper interface and doesn't necessarily correspond to any value you're using.  If you actually *had* a value `sendArgMap` of type `SendArgMap`, then its keys of type `T extends keyof SendArgMap` would be valid `evt` arguments.  And then the result of indexing, `sendArgMap[evt]` would have keys of type `N extends keyof SendArgMap[T]` that would be valid `evn` arguments.  And the result of *that* indexing, `sendArgMap[evt][evn]` would be a value of type `SendArgMap[T][N]`, which would be a valid `evd` argument.  We're using this indexing relationship in the call signature of `send()` without actually needing a value of type `SendArgMap`.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
send(EventType.CHESS, "goback",
    { gameId: "1", count: 5 }); // okay

send(EventType.QUIZ, "answer",
    { gameId: "2", body: "my answer is..." },
    { timeout: 1000 }); // okay

send(EventType.QUIZ, "make_move", // error!
    // ------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    // Argument of type '"make_move"' is not assignable to 
    // parameter of type 'keyof QuizEventList'
    { gameId: "3", from: "2D", to: "4E" },
    { timeout: 1000 }
); //not allowed, should lead to error because "make_move" is CHESS event.
```

Looks good.  The compiler accepts valid calls and rejects invalid ones.  And the IntelliSense suggest/autocomplete functionality also acts as you'd like:

```
// send(EventType.QUIZ, "" // IntelliSense hinting
// --------------------> ^  answer
// --------------------> ^  rate_current
```

Here you are only prompted with the acceptable `evn` arguments.  That's because once you write `EventType.QUIZ` as the `evt` argument, the compiler infers `EventType.QUIZ` as the `T` type, and therefore the `N` type is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof SendArgMap[T]`, which is `keyof QuizEventList`:

```
// function send<EventType.QUIZ, keyof QuizEventList>(⋯): ⋯
```

And so the compiler is able to partially infer the types for you while you're writing the function call and give you appropriate hints.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-GOUngCm04qVWrNegdcgzbgAHwACmAcEQUWQDBjcBAUVznZbkXTSszVZrZp1ubNncsPL5gIlzNZ5e5IcBAEoiXodYad3XkrhG42N9R65v9LmfIMjGMoKtUFAAGJB1dQHxBSBIAJlewcxv6jCuialCdssawbOUOZHNoITOOEUTlHwEFQCcZxQAArFAghrvEuj6JY1RyKg36-v+RrulwIEAkCIKQUc2BQDBYSDuUABMSHQrC8EQPeVHAlIUBFDuhrlJhtF9PRQrACKbb8HQcmYdhuFQPhhHEUqf7OgBbqcBRFRVLUDSWE0nZ6DGWKWFIACEEyEKZAC0DmOU5DmngAfu5Hmea5UA2QQpmZh+EjKWmiAAVAADklQ1PUjTAOU4UCQKICWCUcg5KIQQgHIqzGFgUw+VBSneL4ziPMFUChZgEXJqmXpvJ8eLfIg4W+dBoRwRUADMSEDEMFQsaoSFTPBAAsMAiYIYm9BJojCqKUR8HJdCYWUil6MlqWmJYwI2J29hWGAthQLlch2Pl0iDPxVwKHIYA-np0WGU0iXEGQlBdkghrIrZ+g-uppGuuRIEiaZHCpKYoiKvd5gPHEZT2c5iNI3Zp4AHpQIAvBuAOS7r6Anx8P6MjROOWjmM4yS6KYtiEgE-0z5zmGSrhgD2ncJ2NVpt6DVIE1TaAPdEa5RHzIhYUe8RAA)

Comment: Magnificent solution. Thank You. I was able to move it further and allow narrowing types not only through `send` function like You did in this answer, but also by `if` statements and additionally in declaration itself too. It's in already answered by me SO question, but I am curious what do You think about it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844196/typescript-double-inferring-by-if-statements/75845102?noredirect=1#comment133786964_75845102