# TypeScript: Double inferring by if statements

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inferred-type

Currently I infer type of one property by other property value, but I hit the wall, when I've tried to infer type of one property by second property which is narrowed by third property.

I have a types which describes Game Events, each Game Event is described by 3 properties like so:

- `evt` - type of game
- `evn` - name of event
- `evd` - data associated with event

```
(() => {
    const e: AnyEvent = {} as any;

    if (e.evt === EventType.CHESS && e.evn == "make_move" ) {
        e.evd; // here we want the e.evd type to be correctly inferred as: EventData & {from: string; to: string;}

        //as for now, e.evd is inferred as all possible CHESS event datas:
        /*
            evd: (EventData & {
                from: string;
                to: string;
            }) | (EventData & {
                count: number;
            })
        */
    }

    if (e.evt === EventType.CHESS && e.evn == "goback" ) {
        e.evd; // here we want the e.evd type to be correctly inferred as: EventData & {count: number;}

        //as for now, e.evd is inferred as all possible CHESS event datas:
        /*
            evd: (EventData & {
                from: string;
                to: string;
            }) | (EventData & {
                count: number;
            })
        */
    }

    if (e.evt === EventType.QUIZ && e.evn == "answer" ) {
        e.evd; // here we want the e.evd type to be correctly inferred as: EventData & {body: string;}

        //as for now, e.evd is inferred as all possible QUIZ event datas:
        /*
            evd: (EventData & {
                body: string;
            }) | (EventData & {
                rate: number;
            })
        */
    }
})();
```

whole code is here: [Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAsIGcsFEBuE4AMsFmMgN4BQAkALZwDWEA%20vQPaEBcyBRYACJwwcZADIqdWjCgd6vclFABzANzSwHRWGUh1dAL4a6KjgCNETXv3DDREqbVoIOAV3C8Qb%20uegbaY2pDampQSFhEFABFN2AAL1swUnInOBAsAHdoG0I7ETFJGmdzDgATAE8dPQNAk1ooETYENygoAVyBe0KnBqavHz8oAKCQ6gB6cdCiHz48sAAVCoAHFGLUAAlcAGVtgBo6aIBVAEkALQOx8Oh4JDmBFLAAIQql1acAbSS3iAA6TZ22wAurwMNg8PNHgEvvMfr9jucQchYgkklDgqFJqFrpE7kluk4VHB6BATmVqqoNGMwuAblFkNt5BBtkQygB5ZZgYAcDJOLkk9xgAD8A18-gx1BgHgQXJ5yCwrIAPHRcAA1BbICAAD0gIDKWGQLAqHBg9xIZGerxWEAOtDVADlNTrWQajSazckLS8fl91UDbWrBE7dfqPY9vdbfQsgb77UDqAA%20AAUdAg%20DANnVtrTIEz9uz%20HJfFVgltHE53IyIoZTJZeo5soy1AAlE5Jh9fp342MFXqk99rf8trs9sgAERmSwIJhj0eUZBEklk3hjgCMs%20Qrg8GeQAFZkIZmxpe2V%207DBwiLuP0lloBv54vSUWxwAmDelSor%20gVZA37JQZAyE7X4xwPOdkH5CBBV4VcAAZ4IPI9qBPM8BDhS9RzHRgWHYLgIHvBdiSfFcAGYN1keQVxfQQNy0FcABZcFAwxwMg6DkDghDDzUZBJhADgKDgAAbISOGyMpRywdB3CEspkCEiA4DkrRNTaDgAL8BA4DcBVx2wthOEIUCyDQYdtk1eZfkxKZqDAa1kAAQRACokkVNVcHtBZWAWABNAAFXBgxdD0fmQABeELrQTcLPjVDVQGLDyvN8gKkWKWg0x3OKAgy-Bc0NCBjVNNEvStVYoyBHK0yLEryAjcq4pjN1ishUqfUayqjGCX0ku8-zcE6iYbKTJNWzC6LilcDIKAgXgnJc%20YYsoQxfwNdIKnqYBTSTP5MvCsKIoHVYh0BCRJF2vL9r05gDLw0DW3Si6yh4yZkEwdpkGyT70goMBME1X5qog%20yVL8Td1PaGUhJ-UAYGgdo5LgLBOnyBwigohR5V0SkIO0LGajUMZkGJknicmJHkBgdTkH4zJRyewCDVh%20GIERtaROQZYOBwYBzAU0zTrTARkDKApkeoUnSfGAAqCXJfl6reFQ1GehoeX1ZJjGKX0DQNY1uj8cpOW9cQ5AAB9kGVoQCkcNWTclrdPBpwZxXtxDjcl6WpkCUJaC2y2LooA7DvPY6AV2M6AZzK6JwsKx7t6J6XvGN7oBQL7Mh%20iD-oZuz3lBlBXDaCAoZhkA4eLtmUettGqEdndvDFYYifV8mDSpgDafpwHC0ZwDy5Ztnfw5rmeb5lBw-MoXwBFsXuA9qXZbdxXLfxG2igX%202tcNnXN5Ng2lCNt3D3N1f5gJDe3dJ%20vRSGXX7cPPfkC9rq6H9nae6Dg7IuOy9I4ukAMc-x3mQA9aQSdeIp3eundOWc-ooFziDDgyAwZF0hmAaG-cK4I1WtXC%20VAPxVB3uoFu8s26U2pl3KOvcTLM0rqtYeQlObcywLzfmk8LLC1FqIcWGsZZP1JivK2%20C7ZXxQeUIhh9d7H1bBbYR68pBiOJo0SAt9XYP2bE-F%20PtDyjTUEAA)

and also below here:

```
interface ChessEventList {
    make_move: EventData & {
        from: string;
        to: string;
    };

    goback: EventData & {
        count: number;
    };
}

interface QuizEventList {
    answer: EventData & {
        body: string;
    };

    rate_current: EventData & {
        rate: number;
    };
}

//

enum EventType {
    CHESS,
    QUIZ,
}

interface EventListByType {
    [EventType.CHESS]: ChessEventList;
    [EventType.QUIZ]: QuizEventList;
}

//

interface EventData {
    gameId: string;
}


interface SomeSendOptions {
    timeout?: number;
}

function send<
    EVT extends keyof EventListByType,
    EVN extends keyof EventListByType[EVT],
    EVD extends EventListByType[EVT][EVN]
>(
    evt: EVT,
    evn: EVN,
    evd: EVD,
    options?: SomeSendOptions
) {
    //[...]
}

send(EventType.CHESS, "goback", { gameId: "1", count: 5 });
send(EventType.QUIZ, "answer", { gameId: "2", body: "my answer is..." }, { timeout: 1000 });
send(EventType.QUIZ, "make_move", { gameId: "3", from: "2D", to: "4E" }, { timeout: 1000 }); //not allowed, should lead to error because "make_move" is CHESS event.

//

type AnyEvent<EVENT_TYPE extends EventType = EventType> = {
    [EVT in EVENT_TYPE]: {
        evt: EVT;
        evn: keyof EventListByType[EVT];
        evd: EventListByType[EVT][keyof EventListByType[EVT]];
    }
}[EVENT_TYPE];

//

(() => {
    const e: AnyEvent = {} as any;

    if (e.evt === EventType.CHESS && e.evn == "make_move" ) {
        e.evd; // here we want the e.evd type to be correctly inferred as: EventData & {from: string; to: string;}

        //as for now, e.evd is inferred as all possible CHESS event datas:
        /*
            evd: (EventData & {
                from: string;
                to: string;
            }) | (EventData & {
                count: number;
            })
        */
    }

    if (e.evt === EventType.CHESS && e.evn == "goback" ) {
        e.evd; // here we want the e.evd type to be correctly inferred as: EventData & {count: number;}

        //as for now, e.evd is inferred as all possible CHESS event datas:
        /*
            evd: (EventData & {
                from: string;
                to: string;
            }) | (EventData & {
                count: number;
            })
        */
    }

    if (e.evt === EventType.QUIZ && e.evn == "answer" ) {
        e.evd; // here we want the e.evd type to be correctly inferred as: EventData & {body: string;}

        //as for now, e.evd is inferred as all possible CHESS event datas:
        /*
            evd: (EventData & {
                body: string;
            }) | (EventData & {
                rate: number;
            })
        */
    }
})();
```

I've come up with idea that works well, but I can't tie it together with `EVENT_NAME` generic type, which is required because AnyEvent type should has option to narrowing event kind also in declaration, with `EVENT_TYPE` it's easy, but can't make use of `EVENT_NAME`:

```
type AnyEvent<EVENT_TYPE extends EventType = EventType, EVENT_NAME extends keyof EventListByType[EVENT_TYPE] = keyof EventListByType[EVENT_TYPE]> = {
    [EVT in EVENT_TYPE]: {
        [EVN in keyof EventListByType[EVT]]: {
            evt: EVT,
            evn: EVN,
            evd: EventListByType[EVT][EVN]
        }
    }[keyof EventListByType[EVT]];
}[EVENT_TYPE];
```

Here goes final playground with code above implemented and test cases:

[Final Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAsIGcsFEBuE4AMsFmMgN4BQAkALZwDWEA+vQPaEBcyBRYACJwwcZADIqdWjCgd6vclFABzANzSwHRWGUh1dAL4a6KjgCNETXv3DDREqbVoIOAV3C8Qb+uegbaY2pDampQSFhEFABFN2AAL1swUnInOBAsAHdoG0I7ETFJGmdzDgATAE8dPQNAk1ooETYENygoAVyBe0KnBqavHz8oAKCQ6gB6cdCiHz48sAAVCoAHFGLUAAlcAGVtgBo6aIBVAEkALQOx8Oh4JDmBFLAAIQql1acAbSS3iAA6TZ22wAurwMNg8PNHgEvvMfr9jucQchYgkklDgqFJqFrpE7kluk4VHB6BATmVqqoNGMwuAblFkNt5BBtkQygB5ZZgYAcDJOLkk9xgAD8A18-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-q0yLCrLXGv1Y3jDaQn6wwPjdTLITGyMJqBIEqTy2LCvqkwsWoJMk1bMLGuKVwMgoCBeCclz5iawxfwNdIKnqYBTSTP55vCsKIoHVYh0BCRJHh-A2qRvTmAMvDQNbYpaCxsoeMmZBMHaCDME1X4tog+yTNcNoIBlISf1AGBoHaOS4CwTp8gcIoKIUeVdEpCDtAlmo1BCQJQloGHkDhhn00R5Hz1RgFdgx+mc0R8dJysInejJinxip6AUDAOmyaZ94WfU9oOa5kAebZ-nBY9Akii3TxkG8MVhgVsZldhrGKCRrW0IvU4zn1rGcYisc-zvZBiekC3eKt6nbft9XlOZg1WddsBOdaz2+fBoWhAKRxKA-KpZcpMOlcpu2UGWORzAU+hAINPxRMybgld+1IIBfQHnNclG-kvRqIpJ+buDtbWF4T21Sextex0aSBWBaNnwA3SY02gCo7dUQfkBgUAbWQbIqbgPIAHIKBAOA1PEwCKFAeSD9eAAAMJ7-Wno5We8w3Ib3hAnBMwDfh-03OkZAfhrwZH-KBdS44D7NFaO0U+2dCxr0oI+Zc451yjjwTBWCYd6hgM1CRGewMBAwLjqjDCGDbxQDHEvc26Y17zzgecbeq1aD7yaEfAhAgz7jCkjJOSCklLS1UnIKAo5NLaV0s-L+P8IByWAP-NqQkgHIFATySezDIGsPAOw8A6Et7cKwQg1R6CeSVzTpgu8xDyS0DIURCha4Nw0I4nQowVJmwfTUEAA)

I put test cases also here:

```
(() => {
    const e: AnyEvent = {} as any;

    if (e.evt === EventType.CHESS && e.evn == "make_move" ) {
        e.evd; // here the e.evd type is correctly inferred as: EventData & {from: string; to: string;}
    }

    if (e.evt === EventType.CHESS && e.evn == "goback" ) {
        e.evd; // here the e.evd type is correctly inferred as: EventData & {count: number;}
    }

    if (e.evt === EventType.QUIZ && e.evn == "answer" ) {
        e.evd; // here the e.evd type is correctly inferred as: EventData & {body: string;}
    }

    // the problem is below:

    const e2: AnyEvent<EventType.QUIZ> = {
        evt:    EventType.QUIZ,
        evn:    "rate_current", //everything is fine, we haven't narrowed it in line: `const e2: AnyEvent<EventType.QUIZ>`. it can be "answer" or "rate_current"
        evd:    {gameId: "1", rate: 10}
    };

    const e3: AnyEvent<EventType.QUIZ, "answer"> = {
        evt:    EventType.QUIZ,
        evn:    "rate_current", //should lead to error, because we narrowed it in line: `const e3: AnyEvent<EventType.QUIZ, "answer">` to be only "answer"
        evd:    {gameId: "1", rate: 10}
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found solution:

```
type AnyEvent<EVENT_TYPE extends EventType = EventType, EVENT_NAME extends (keyof EventListByType[EVENT_TYPE] | never) = never> = {
    [EVT in EVENT_TYPE]: {
        [EVN in ([EVENT_NAME] extends [never] ? keyof EventListByType[EVT] : EVENT_NAME)]: {
            evt: EVT,
            evn: EVN,
            evd: EventListByType[EVT][EVN]
        }
    }[([EVENT_NAME] extends [never] ? keyof EventListByType[EVT] : EVENT_NAME)];
}[EVENT_TYPE];
```

Here in code above I used `never` as a placeholding value, and then inside of `[EVT in EVENT_TYPE]: {` reveal `never` as desired `EventListByType` but with iterating product `EVT` like so: `EventListByType[EVT]` - of course only then when it's `never` otherwise use provided value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to build a typing system within a typing system and I don't really know why.

The fundamentals of the call signatures you want can be achieved as Tuples as below, without building a type system.

However, it's much more conventional to use [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions) that are objects and not have to reason about spreading them over an arg list, which seems unnecessary to me...

```js
interface SomeSendOptions {
  timeout?: number;
}

type MakeMoveTuple = [
  "chess",
  "makemove",
  {
    from: string;
    to: string;
  },
  SomeSendOptions  
];

type GoBackTuple = [
  "chess",
  "goback",
  {
    count:number
  },
    SomeSendOptions  
];

type GameTuple = MakeMoveTuple | GoBackTuple

function send<T extends GameTuple>(...tuple:T) {
    const [typeName, actionName, actionOptions, sendOptions] = tuple;
    if(typeName==="chess"){
        if(actionName==="makemove"){
            const { from, to } = actionOptions
        }
        if(actionName==="goback"){
            const { count } = actionOptions
        }
    }
}

send("chess", "makemove", { "from": "something", "to": "something"}, {timeout:2000})
send("chess", "goback", { "count": 3}, {timeout:2000})
```

Comment: It looks like You have clicked wrong link, my question isn't about send function.

Comment: Hi Sonaht. This illustrates how defining events as tuples (if you want to string args out in a row for some reason) is one way to infer argument types from earlier args in a sequence. More conventionally you would not use tuples (send would have a single event arg - and events would be objects with named parameters). You wanted inference correctly for the third arg to send, right?

Comment: No, send function works perfectly fine already. The error I am facing with is in line: `evn:    "rate_current", //should lead to error, because we narrowed it in line: \`const e3: AnyEvent<EventType.QUIZ, "answer">\` to be only "answer"` at the end of SO question.